# Clone Image Without Empty Blocks

Tags: iso-image, clone, dd, compact-flash, knoppix

I've been using `dd if/mnt/sda1/images/$1  of=/dev/$2` to clone some embedded images for compact flashes. I used to only be using one brand of CFs, but, now I have two of them (both 2g, but obviously different amount of blocks) and the DD image is too big for the second brand.

How can I copy the image and ignore the empty blocks so I can fit the image on the new card? I know I can't use DD anymore and I saw reference to `ntfsclone` in my googling. What would be an effective way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a block level copy and not a file level copy?

Comment: Indeed, why not just copy the files? Also, you’re using *nix right? You can add an OS-specific tag to ensure you get the most applicable answers.

Comment: @jidar I edited it for knoppix, and I was using block level because it leaves it as an ISO. Will a file level copy compact into an ISO as well?